# Sending ajax request by jquery doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send ajax request to api. My code is

```
$(".doit").click(function(){
    console.log("GG");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "localhost:8000/api/get-user/1",
        data: {id:1},
        success: function(res) { 
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
})
```

It's just a simple code. Everyone know. But it works in "console.log("GG"). Not working in ajax part.
I monitored the network traffic by firefox, but I ddin't see any network traffic.
Do you have any idea about that case?

Comment: just give page name insted sending whole url in URL

Comment: You have to provide an online running example or a snippet in order for us to be able to determine what's not working. Did you check your Network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: may b problem in url. check your console for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your ajax URL as below

```
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/get-user/1",
```

or

```
url: "api/get-user/1",
```

Hope this will fix your issue

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much Mr.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are specifying the port number, and also not including the scheme.

Simply removing your domain should be enough:

```
$(".doit").click(function(){
    console.log("GG");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/api/get-user/1",
        data: {id:1},
        success: function(res) { 
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: But, the api is run on laravel. How to do that? I mean the api is different project.

Comment: You don't touch laravel, you just remove the domain from your ajax call. See my answer again. you will notice I changed your url from `"localhost:8000/api/get-user/1"` to `"/api/get-user/1"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not specify the URL scheme. So, instead of `localhost:8000/api/get-user/1` you should use `//localhost:8000/api/get-user/1`, or better specify just the relative path `/api/get-user/1`.

Answer (score -1):

I think because your url in the same url as you want to make request and that didn't make you will see the network traffic. just using the different url will show the request ajax from the network traffic.

just try to change your url to this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
and read about this further information: https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to